# Custom config file copy defaults like config.yml

Tags: java, file, config, bukkit

I want to create custom config files because I am making very big plugin, and the problem is I want to copydefaults like config.yml in my custom badwords.yml. How do I do that? I've tried using the copydefault like the config.yml is using but that does not work. Here is the code:

```
package me.herobrine112211.ulticmdpack;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import net.milkbowl.vault.economy.Economy;
import net.milkbowl.vault.economy.EconomyResponse;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.Location;
import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.World;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.configuration.InvalidConfigurationException;
import org.bukkit.configuration.file.FileConfiguration;
import org.bukkit.configuration.file.YamlConfiguration;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.player.AsyncPlayerChatEvent;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerCommandPreprocessEvent;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerJoinEvent;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerMoveEvent;
import org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack;
import org.bukkit.inventory.PlayerInventory;
import org.bukkit.plugin.RegisteredServiceProvider;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class System extends JavaPlugin implements Listener{

    public File BadWordsFile = new File(getDataFolder()+"/Data/badwords.yml");
    public FileConfiguration badwordsdata = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(BadWordsFile);

    ArrayList<String> frozen = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Player> cooldown = new ArrayList<Player>();

    public static Economy econ = null;

    public void saveFiles(){
        try {
            badwordsdata.save(BadWordsFile);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void loadFiles(){
        if(BadWordsFile.exists()){
        try {
            badwordsdata.load(BadWordsFile);
        } catch (IOException | InvalidConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }else{
            try {
                badwordsdata.options().copyDefaults(true);
                badwordsdata.save(BadWordsFile);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void onEnable() {
        if (!setupEconomy()){
            getLogger().severe(String.format("[%s] - Disabled because vault was not found!", getDescription().getName()));
            getServer().getPluginManager().disablePlugin(this);
            return;
        }
        getConfig().options().copyDefaults(true);
        saveConfig();
        loadFiles();
        Bukkit.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this);
        Bukkit.getServer().getLogger().info(ChatColor.GREEN + "Ultimate Command Pack Plugin has been actived!");
        Bukkit.getServer().getScheduler().scheduleSyncRepeatingTask(this, new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Bukkit.getServer().broadcastMessage(ChatColor.WHITE + "[" + ChatColor.GOLD + "ANNOUNCEMENT" + ChatColor.WHITE + "]" + ChatColor.YELLOW + "Server creator: Herobrine112211!");
            }
        }, 100, 1400);
    }

    private boolean setupEconomy(){
        if (getServer().getPluginManager().getPlugin("Vault") == null){
            return false;
        }
        RegisteredServiceProvider<Economy> rsp = getServer().getServicesManager().getRegistration(Economy.class);
        if(rsp == null){
            return false;
        }
        econ = rsp.getProvider();
        return econ !=null;
    }

    public void onDisable() {
        saveFiles();
        Bukkit.getServer().getLogger().info(ChatColor.GREEN + "All files have been saved!");
        Bukkit.getServer().getLogger().info(ChatColor.GREEN + "Ultimate Command Pack Plugin has been disabled! This will give big problems to server.");
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void onPlayerJoin(PlayerJoinEvent joinevent){
        Player getplayer = joinevent.getPlayer();
        getplayer.sendMessage(ChatColor.AQUA + "Hey " + getplayer.getName() + "! Welcome to the Ultimate Prison server!");
        // Spawning player in spawn location
        if(getConfig().getConfigurationSection("spawn") == null){
            getplayer.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Spawn is not set!. Report this problem to owner INSTANTLY!");
        }
        World w = Bukkit.getServer().getWorld(getConfig().getString("spawn.world"));
        double x = getConfig().getDouble("spawn.x");
        double y = getConfig().getDouble("spawn.y");
        double z = getConfig().getDouble("spawn.z");
        getplayer.teleport(new Location(w, x, y, z));
        // ----------------------------------------------------------------
        if(getplayer.getName().equals("Herobrine112211")){
            Bukkit.getServer().broadcastMessage(ChatColor.WHITE + "[" + ChatColor.GOLD + "BROADCAST" + ChatColor.WHITE + "] " + ChatColor.GOLD + "Server Creator Herobrine112211 has joined the game!!!!!!!!!!");
        }
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void onPlayerMove(PlayerMoveEvent moveevent) {
        Player getplayer = moveevent.getPlayer();
        if(frozen.contains(getplayer.getName())){
            moveevent.setTo(moveevent.getFrom());
        }
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void onPlayerChat(AsyncPlayerChatEvent chatevent){
        for (String word : chatevent.getMessage().split(" ")){
            if(badwordsdata.getStringList("badwords").contains(word)){
                if (!chatevent.getPlayer().hasPermission("bypassbadwords")){
                chatevent.setCancelled(true);
                chatevent.getPlayer().sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Dont use dirty (bad) words!");
             }
          }
        }
     }

    @EventHandler
    public void onPlayerCommand(PlayerCommandPreprocessEvent commandevent){
        String msg = commandevent.getMessage().toLowerCase();
        if(msg.startsWith("/op")){
            commandevent.setCancelled(true);
            commandevent.getPlayer().sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Op command is only for owner.");
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String commandLabel, String[] args){

            if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("contactowner")) {
                if (!sender.hasPermission("contactowner")){
                    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Access denied.");
                    return true;
                }
                if (!(sender instanceof Player)) {
                    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Console will never need owner support.");
                    return true;
                }
                if(sender instanceof Player){
                    Player player = (Player) sender;
                player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "Owner: Herobrine112211. Live chat skype: gangsteris33.");
                return true;
                }
            }

            if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("reloadconfig")){
                if (!sender.hasPermission("config.reload")){
                    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Access denied.");
                    return true;
                }
                reloadConfig();
                sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Server config reloaded successfully.");
                return true;
            }

            if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("saveconfig")){
                if (!sender.hasPermission("config.save")){
                    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Access denied.");
                    return true;
                }
                reloadConfig();
                sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Server config saved successfully.");
                return true;
            }

            if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("fakeop")) {
                if (!sender.hasPermission("fake.op")){
                    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Access denied.");
                    return true;
                }
                if (args.length == 0) {
                    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Please specify a player!");
                    return true;
                }
                Player target = Bukkit.getServer().getPlayer(args[0]);
                if (target == null) {
                    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Player must be online!");
                    return true;
                }
                target.sendMessage(ChatColor.YELLOW + "You are now op!");
                return true;
            }

            if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("fakejoin")) {
                if (!sender.hasPermission("fake.join")){
                    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Access denied.");
                    return true;
                }
                if (args.length == 0) {
                    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Please specify a name!");
                    return true;
                }
                Bukkit.getServer().broadcastMessage(ChatColor.YELLOW + args[0] + " joined the game.");
                return true;
            }

            if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("broadcast")) {
                if (!sender.hasPermission("broadcast")){
                    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Access denied.");
                    return true;
                }
                if (args.length == 0) {
                    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Please give a message to broadcast!");
                    return true;
                }
                StringBuilder strbl = new StringBuilder();
                for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++){
                    strbl.append(args[i] + " ");
                }
                String broadcastas = strbl.toString();
                Bukkit.getServer().broadcastMessage(ChatColor.WHITE + "[" + ChatColor.GOLD + "BROADCAST" + ChatColor.WHITE + "] " + ChatColor.RED + broadcastas);
                return true;
            }

            if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("heal")) {
                if (!sender.hasPermission("heal")){
                    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Access denied.");
                    return true;
                }
                if (!(sender instanceof Player)) {
                    if (args.length == 0) {
                        sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Please specify a player!");
                        return true;
                }
                    Player target = Bukkit.getServer().getPlayer(args[0]);
                    if (target == null) {
                        sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Player must be online to be healed!");
                            return true;
                    }
                    target.setHealth(20);
                    target.setFireTicks(0);
                    target.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "CONSOLE" + " healed you!");
                    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + target.getName() + " is healed!");
                    return true;
                }
                    if(sender instanceof Player){
                    if (args.length == 0) {
                        Player player = (Player) sender;
                            player.setHealth(20);
                            player.setFireTicks(0);
                            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "Your health is now full!");
                            return true;
                    }
                    Player target = Bukkit.getServer().getPlayer(args[0]);
                    if (target == null) {
                        sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Player must be online to be healed!");
                            return true;
                    }
                    Player player = (Player) sender;
                    target.setHealth(20);
                    target.setFireTicks(0);
                    target.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + player.getName() + " healed you!");
                    player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + target.getName() + " is healed!");
                    return true;
                    }
            }

            if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("kill")) {
                if (!sender.hasPermission("kill")){
                    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Access denied.");
                    return true;
                }
                if (!(sender instanceof Player)) {
                    if (args.length == 0) {
                        sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Please specify a player!");
                        return true;
                }
                    Player target = Bukkit.getServer().getPlayer(args[0]);
                    if (target == null) {
                        sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Player must be online to be killed!");
                            return true;
                    }
                    target.setHealth(0);
                    target.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "CONSOLE" + " killed you!");
                    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + target.getName() + " is killed!");
                    return true;
                    }
                if(sender instanceof Player){
                    if (args.length == 0) {
                        Player player = (Player) sender;
                            player.setHealth(0);
                            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "You killed your self!");
                            return true;
                    }
                    Player target = Bukkit.getServer().getPlayer(args[0]);
                    if (target == null) {
                        sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Player must be online to be killed!");
                            return true;
                    }
                    Player player = (Player) sender;
                    target.setHealth(0);
                    target.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + player.getName() + " killed you!");
                    player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + target.getName() + " is killed!");
                    return true;
                    }
            }

            if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("feed")) {
                if (!sender.hasPermission("feed")){
                    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Access denied.");
                    return true;
                }
                if (!(sender instanceof Player)) {
                    if (args.length == 0) {
                        sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Please specify a player!");
                        return true;
                }
                    Player target = Bukkit.getServer().getPlayer(args[0]);
                    if (target == null) {
                        sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Player must be online to be fed!");
                            return true;
                    }
                    target.setHealth(20);
                    target.setFireTicks(0);
                    target.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "CONSOLE" + " fed you!");
                    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + target.getName() + " hunger is now full!");
                    return true;
                }
                if(sender instanceof Player){
                if (args.length == 0) {
                    Player player = (Player) sender;
                        player.setFoodLevel(20);
                        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "Your hunger is now full!");
                        return true;
                }
                Player target = Bukkit.getServer().getPlayer(args[0]);
                if (target == null) {
                    Player player = (Player) sender;
                    player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Player must be online to be fed!");
                        return true;
                }
                Player player = (Player) sender;
                target.setFoodLevel(20);
                target.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + player.getName() + " fed you!");
                player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + target.getName() + " hunger is now full!");
                return true;
                }
        }

            if(cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("tpall")){
                if (!sender.hasPermission("teleport")){
                    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Access denied.");
                    return true;
                }
                if (!(sender instanceof Player)) {
                    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Cannot teleport everyone to console!");
                    return true;
                }
                if(sender instanceof Player){
                if(args.length == 0){
                    for(Player allplayers : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()) {
                        Player player = (Player) sender;
                        World w = player.getLocation().getWorld();
                        double x = player.getLocation().getX();
                        double y = player.getLocation().getY();
                        double z = player.getLocation().getZ();
                        allplayers.teleport(new Location(w, x, y, z));
                        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "All players teleported to you!");
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                for(Player allplayers : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()) {
                    Player target = Bukkit.getServer().getPlayer(args[0]);
                    if(target == null){
                        Player player = (Player) sender;
                        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Player must be online!");
                        return true;
                    }
                    Player player = (Player) sender;
                    World w = target.getLocation().getWorld();
                    double x = target.getLocation().getX();
                    double y = target.getLocation().getY();
                    double z = target.getLocation().getZ();
                    allplayers.teleport(new Location(w, x, y, z));
                    player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "All players teleported to player!");
                    return true;
                }
              }
            }

            if(cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("setspawn")){
                if (!sender.hasPermission("setspawn")){
                    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Access denied.");
                    return true;
                }
                if (!(sender instanceof Player)) {
                    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "CONSOLE Cannot set spawn!");
                    return true;
                }
                if(sender instanceof Player){
                Player player = (Player) sender;
                getConfig().set("spawn.world", player.getLocation().getWorld().getName());
                getConfig().set("spawn.x", player.getLocation().getX());
                getConfig().set("spawn.y", player.getLocation().getY());
                getConfig().set("spawn.z", player.getLocation().getZ());
                saveConfig();
                player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "Spawn has been set!");
                return true;
                }
            }

            if(cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("checkworld")){
                String worldName = getConfig().getString("spawn.world");
                Bukkit.getLogger().info(worldName);
                return true;
            }

            if(cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("spawn")){
                if (!sender.hasPermission("spawn")){
                    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Access denied.");
                    return true;
                }
                if (!(sender instanceof Player)) {
                    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "CONSOLE Cannot teleport to spawn!");
                    return true;
                }
                if(getConfig().getConfigurationSection("spawn") == null){
                    Player player = (Player) sender;
                    player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Spawn is not set!");
                    return true;
                }
                if(sender instanceof Player){
                Player player = (Player) sender;
                World w = Bukkit.getServer().getWorld(getConfig().getString("spawn.world"));
                double x = getConfig().getDouble("spawn.x");
                double y = getConfig().getDouble("spawn.y");
                double z = getConfig().getDouble("spawn.z");
                player.teleport(new Location(w, x, y, z));
                return true;
                }
            }

            if(cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("freeze")){
                if (!sender.hasPermission("freeze")){
                    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Access denied.");
                    return true;
                }
                if(args.length == 0){
                    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Please specify a player!");
                    return true;
                }
                Player target = Bukkit.getServer().getPlayer(args[0]);
                if(target == null){
                    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Player must be online!");
                    return true;
                }
                if(frozen.contains(target.getName())){
                    frozen.remove(target.getName());
                    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + target.getName() + " is now unfrozen!");
                    return true;
                }
                frozen.add(target.getName());
                sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + target.getName() + " is now frozen!");
                target.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "You have been frozen by administrator.");
                return true;
            }

            if(cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("kit")){
                if (!(sender instanceof Player)) {
                    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "CONSOLE Cannot get kits!" + ChatColor.RED + "Kits:" + ChatColor.GOLD + "Starter");
                    return true;
                }
                if (!sender.hasPermission("kit")){
                    sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Access denied.");
                    return true;
                }
                if(sender instanceof Player){
                    if(args.length == 0){
                        Player player = (Player) sender;
                        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Kits:" + ChatColor.GOLD + " Starter");
                        return true;
                    }
                    if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("starter")){
                        if (!sender.hasPermission("kit.starter")){
                            sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Access denied.");
                            return true;
                        }

                        final Player player2 = (Player) sender;
                        if(cooldown.contains(player2)){
                            player2.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "You cannot get this kit yet!. You can get kits every 24 hours.");
                            if (player2.hasPermission("kit.bypass")){
                                cooldown.remove(player2);
                                player2.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "Admin access detected. Kit cooldown removed. Try again :)");
                                return true;
                            }
                            return true;
                        }

                        if(sender instanceof Player){
                            Player player = (Player) sender;
                            PlayerInventory pinv = player.getInventory();
                            EconomyResponse withdraw = econ.withdrawPlayer(player.getName(), 10);
                            if(withdraw.transactionSuccess()){
                                pinv.addItem(new ItemStack(Material.DIAMOND_PICKAXE, 1));
                                pinv.addItem(new ItemStack(Material.DIAMOND_SWORD, 1));
                                pinv.addItem(new ItemStack(Material.DIAMOND_AXE, 1));
                                pinv.addItem(new ItemStack(Material.COOKED_BEEF, 20));
                                cooldown.add(player);
                                Bukkit.getServer().getScheduler().scheduleSyncDelayedTask(this, new Runnable(){
                                    public void run(){
                                        cooldown.remove(player2);
                                    }
                                }, 1728000);
                                return true;
                            }
                            else {
                                player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "You dont have required money ammount. Kit purchase failed!");
                                return true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    Player player = (Player) sender;
                    player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Kit was not found. Do /kit for kits.");
                    return true;
                }
            }
        return false;
   }
}
```

If you dont understand, I mean that I want to copy badwords.yml file from the plugin if it doesn't exist. I hope that is more clear.

Updated code:

[CLICK ME](http://pastebin.com/mjfEKxE7)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly if I were you I would stick by Java Naming Conventions

> Except for variables, all instance, class, and class constants are in mixed case with a **lowercase first letter**. Internal words start with capital letters. Variable names should not start with underscore _ or dollar sign $ characters, even though both are allowed. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html

```
public File BadWordsFile = new File(getDataFolder()+"/Data/badwords.yml");
public FileConfiguration badwordsdata = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(BadWordsFile);
```

becomes

```
public File badWordsFile = new File(getDataFolder()+"/Data/badwords.yml");
public FileConfiguration badWordsData = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(badWordsFile);
```

---

As for your problem just check if it exists, if it doesn't then create it then copy in the default 'badwords'.

```
if (!badWordsFile.exists()) {
    badWordsFile.createNewFile();
    //copy in default 'badwords'

    List<String> listOfBadWords = Arrays.asList("BadWord", "AnotherBadWord", "AlsoABadWord");
    badWordsData.set("badwords", listOfBadWords);
}
```

I would also  run the above and initialize the `badWordsFile` & `badwordsdata` in the in the `onEnable()` method.

EDIT: Try looking at this on the bukkit wiki: http://wiki.bukkit.org/Configuration_API_Reference#Mirroring_the_JavaPlugin_implementation particularly at the Implementation for Reloading:

```
public void reloadCustomConfig() {
    if (customConfigFile == null) {
        customConfigFile = new File(getDataFolder(), "customConfig.yml");
    }
    customConfig = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(customConfigFile);

    // Look for defaults in the jar
    Reader defConfigStream = new InputStreamReader(this.class.getResource("customConfig.yml"), "UTF-8");
    if (defConfigStream != null) {
        YamlConfiguration defConfig = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(defConfigStream);
        customConfig.setDefaults(defConfig);
    }
}
```

You could adapt it as follows

```
public File badWordsFile;
public FileConfiguration badWordsData;

public void saveDefaultConfigValues() {
    badWordsFile = new File(getDataFolder() + "/Data/badwords.yml");
    badWordsData = YAMLConfiguration.loadConfiguration(badWordsFile);
    //Defaults in jar
    Reader defConfigStream;
    try {
        defConfigStream = new InputStreamReader(this.class.getResource("badwords.yml"), "UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (defConfigStream != null) {
        YamlConfiguration defConfig = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(defConfigStream);
        badWordsData.setDefaults(defConfig);
        //Copy default values
        badWordsData.options().copyDefaults(true);
        this.saveConfig();
        //OR use this to copy default values
        //this.saveDefaultConfig();
    }
}
```

Now you can just call this method in the `onEnable()` method.

Comment: the file got created but its empty it does not have anything from the file that is in plugin. badwords.yml it should copy it like the config does.

Comment: Edited it, you can try what I added below the previous stuff.

Comment: Umm... I dont understand soo i copy that and paste in the enable and i can keep my loadfiles and savefiles right? but if i add reloadcustomconfig i think it will load defaults everytime the server start. Yes i want to get the file from the plugin (defaults) like config if the file does not exist and that does not have the if statement. Soo can you explain more or something.

Comment: AND customConfig does not exist (cannot be resolved)

Comment: OK, I edited it, change customConfig to badWordsData. Add your reloadCustomConfig in onEnable() method and it should copy default values out of the jar

Comment: Changed the method name to saveDefaultConfigValues

Comment: The method saveConfig() is undefined for the type FileConfiguration how do i fix that?

Comment: Sorry use this.saveConfig() not badWordsData.saveConfig()

Comment: one more error in this line: Reader defConfigStream = new InputStreamReader(this.getResource("badwords.yml"), "UTF8"); the error is: Unhandled exception type UnsupportedEncodingException i can use quick fix try/catch but that will give another error.

Comment: It should work if you create the variable outside the try/catch then set it inside the try/catch

Comment: Check the updated code i added. When i tested it the file was not created and i got 1 warnings in console. What did i do wrong? yes i know that public File badWordsFile;
public FileConfiguration badWordsData;

is missing at the top it does not matter. Its the same. Warning is: The system cannot find the path specified

Comment: Ok everything is ok but getResource does not exist. What do i add in that created method?

Comment: I'm not sure why bukkit had it like that but it should be this.class.getResource

Comment: New errors:

The method saveDefaultConfigValues() is undefined for the type SystemManager

getDataFolder cannot be resolved to a variable

Syntax error on token "class", Identifier expected

Its messed up. Oh and i am doing configs in a manager now i created. That would be easyer in the future. Here is the manager code: http://pastebin.com/Ttm3hRV5 yes right now in the mess i tried fixing the problem i have with the custom config my self ignore the left stuff about it. First we need to fix those problems.

Comment: I accidentally deleted the two brackets after getDataFolder, it should be getDataFolder(). Is this your main class file in your plugin? Because if it is, then the class should be extending JavaPlugin (like it does in your original). Are you sure you meant to use Plugin not JavaPlugin or whatever your main class is if this is not your main class. Also saveDefaultConfigValeus() should be outside the setup() method. I would also rename your method names so they don't overwrite the JavaPlugin/Plugin ones if this is your main class.

Comment: This is an example of what I would think it would look like if it was the main class: http://pastebin.com/UgN2YrRF

Comment: Syntax error on token "class", Identifier expected error. if its in my systemmanager that its not my main class and the getdatafolder error too. If its in my main class getdatafolder error and InputStreamReader cannot be resolved to a type. I would like it that it would be not in my main class in the systemmanager but it does not matter i can make it in my main class.